# Download video from Telegram given the URL

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a message link on Telegram such as https://t.me/channelName/1234 , which is a video.

How do I download it programatically? I want to plug the link into a script and have it downloaded to my local hard drive.

Can't find any semblance of a tutorial on this online. Thanks